# SOC2 and the CentOS root user

Tags: centos, root

One of our customers has the following requirement: according to SOC2 they need to block access to the CentOS root account.

They mean any access, even with `su root` or `sudo su`.

We have blocked the SSH access, but they claim it is not enough.

Do you know where in SOC2 possible to find the requirements to block access to an OS root account?

Comment: If your customer has SOC 2, then they have that document. And I don't think it's in the official standards. This is your customer's policy. Ask to see their policies and ask how they manage their Linux machines.

Comment: Compliance vs Security. Most auditors mean that it should not be possible to login to the root account directly and that administrative commands should be carried out using sudo. This avoids administrative tasks being carried on a shared account, supporting the philosophy of logging and individual accountability for all actions. This can easily be done by locking the root account password with `passwd --lock root` in most cases. As to where SOC2 states this, I cannot find any source.